# Java- convert two strings to single string

Tags: java, string

I have two strings

```
String str1= "B0000001";
String str2= "Testing";

StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1)
sb.append("\\");
sb.append(str2);
return sb.toString();
```

I get the result as "B0000001"\"Testing"

But I want the result as "B0000001\Testing"

How can I achieve it?

Comment: It is working perfectly.. it seems you have compiled with different code

Comment: `"B0000001"\"Testing"` is only possible if you use `sb.append("\"\\\"");`.

Comment: This obviously isn't the actual running code; it's missing half its semicolons.  And the code posted cannot produce the stated outcome.

Comment: Check this http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/12422 your code giving expected output

Comment: @user2208325 is the output you are showing from a debugger or a console? A debugger might auto-escape strings, whereas a console would not.

Comment: The output from this code is `B0000001\Testing` i run it , so what the output you want???

Comment: if you are recompiling you should remove all .class files first.

Comment: My question is I need to remove "\" from the result= "B0000001"\"Testing" and change it as result="B0000001\Testing"

Comment: it works fine, however you are missing a few semicolons:
http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/12424

Comment: POST THE ACTUAL CODE YOU'RE RUNNING!!!

Comment: Is there any way, I can remove " from string if we have any extra in the string like example: ""test""-> I need to change it to "test"

Comment: this `""test""` is error in java , it write `"\"test\""`

Comment: @user2208325 you don't need to remove the `"` if you don't put it in the result string in the first place. But since you won't post the _real_ code that you're using, we can't help with that.

Answer (score 3):

```
  String str1 = "B0000001";
  String str2 = "Testing";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(str1);
  sb.append("\"\\\"");///////////(\")--->for (") and (\\) for(\) and (\")-->for (")
  sb.append(str2);
  System.out.println( sb.toString());
```

The output is :**B0000001"\"Testing**

```
String str1= "B0000001"
String str2= "Testing"

StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1)
sb.append("\\");
sb.append(str2);
return sb.toString();
```

The output is :**B0000001\Testing**